# Get value with JQuery value from Table

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, view, model

I have a View that passes `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Entities.Movie>` which dumps out a List of Movie's in a table for me.

I am trying to get a value of `item.ID`.

The following code gives me **text input in *item-field***, but I am not sure how to manipulate this location to get the value of the input above it.

```
var name1 = $field.find(":input:first").val();
```

Here is my entire JQuery for overview

```
<script>
        $(document.documentElement)
        .on("click", "span.item-display", function (event) {
            $(event.currentTarget)
                .hide()
                .next("span.item-field")
                .show()
                .find(":input:first")
                .focus()
                .select();
        })
        .on("focusout", "span.item-field", function (event) {
            console.log("this is a log");
            var $field = $(event.currentTarget),
            $display = $field.prev("span.item-display");
            $display.html($field.find(":input:first").val());
            $display.show();
            $field.hide();

            var name1 = $field.find(":input:first").val(); // <-- this gets Blue Whales

            $.post(
                '@Url.Action("UpdateTitle", "Movie")',
                 {
                     'id': '1', // <-- I want this to be the "value"
                     'name': name1
                 },
                function (data) { },
                "json"
            );
        });
    </script>
```

EDIT:
My friend is trying to give me a helping hand, he just added this to my code

```
<span style="visibility:hidden;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>
```

which sits right on the area my currentTarget is at, the snippet together looks like

```
<td class="col-lg-2">

      <span style="visibility:hidden;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>
            <span class="item-display">
                   <span style="font-size: 17px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</span>
            </span>   
       <span class="item-field">
                   @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)   
       </span>

</td>
```

Now I should be able to somehow find this value (item.ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

to get the model in jquery variable

```
var dataViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

cycle them

```
dataViewModel.each(function(index){
    //get property
    var id=dataviewMode[index].ID;
});
```

update

http://jsfiddle.net/Rnv8m/1/

```
alert($("#text2").prev("input:text:first").val());

<div>
    <input type="text" id="text1" value="ABC"/>
    <input type="text" id="text2" value="DEF"/>
</div>
```

replace my `$("#text2")` with your `$(event.currentTarget)`

Comment: I drastically updated my question, can you help with it now? Thanks!

Comment: hmmm I did an alert(); on it and it was blank... do you need to see more of the code or something?

Comment: can you post it in a fiddle?

Comment: I can try too, I just added another image for you to see the "values=number" that I need.

Comment: If this makes, here is how I am trying to use your code to backtrack. I just need to go back one "input" and get it's value from the $(even.currenTarget)'s location, like:  $(event.currentTarget).prev("input").find("input[type=text]").attr('value').val();

Comment: I get an "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: says undefined. Hmm, I shall keep trying more combinations. I am not sure why this value is so hard to get.

Comment: this means that your $(event.currentTarget) is not an input.. try getting its ID.

Comment: look at my updated post, my friend gave me a helper to find the ID

Comment: $(event.currentTarget).prev("input").find("input[type=text]").parent().parent().parent().parent().find("input:text:first").attr('value').val(‌​);

Comment: Do I need that many parents to go to the span before this? In my code the span item-field is just before the new span my friend added that has the item ID

Comment: I THINK I GOT IT!! alert($(this).prev("span").prev("span").text());

Comment: I was watching your html structure and seems to be located at that level. Because you have input inside span inside tr inside table. So once you get the table you can re-enter in the tree searching for your input.

Comment: if you post a fiddle with the same structure I can give you the exact answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54793/discussion-between-faby-and-austin).